# Overflow hidden no having affect

Tags: react-native

I have a simple progress bar, it has a borderRadius and overflow set to `hidden`. I have a child of this, it has no borderRadius, and it is overflowing outside of the corners. Here is my markup:

```
        <View style={style.progressbar}>
            <View style={[style.progressbarfill, { width:'50%' }]} />
        </View>



const style = { 
    progressbar: {
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        height: 25,
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 12,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    progressbarfill: {
        backgroundColor: 'springgreen',
        width: '10%',
        height: '100%'
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I put arrows on where the green is covering the border. The green should not overflow outside the edges.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'm testing it right now, seems to be working fine on iOS, but Android is the one having the issue with the overflow right now. It looks like that is still getting more support currently. A temporary fix, is to just add the same borderRadius on the progressbarfill.

Here is the issue on the React Native Docs:

> The overflow style property defaults to hidden and cannot be changed
>   on Android  This is a result of how Android rendering works. This
>   feature is not being worked on as it would be a significant
>   undertaking and there are many more important tasks.
>
> Another issue with overflow: 'hidden' on Android: a view is not
>   clipped by the parent's borderRadius even if the parent has overflow:
>   'hidden' enabled – the corners of the inner view will be visible
>   outside of the rounded corners. This is only on Android; it works as
>   expected on iOS. See the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198).

Comment: Ooo thank you very much Taylor for this. Is this where you read about it - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/known-issues.html#the-overflow-style-property-defaults-to-hidden-and-cannot-be-changed-on-android ?

Comment: Yeah! No problem. I was researching a little bit more for newer releases you might check your version for React native and see if those release notes pertain to you. I know those are a little outdated, but I couldn't find any newer releases that fixed this, but maybe? I have 0.42 and I'm still having this issue...so if you solve it! Let me know! @Noitidart

Comment: Thanks for that note I will for sure let you know. I am also on 0.42 :)

Comment: No worries, and good luck! Here is the github issue, that was last commented on 13 days ago. It seems overflow + border-radius is the issue still, but you could follow this thread for potential future updates: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198

Answer (score 2):

I found that, in addition to `overflow: 'hidden'` needed on the parent, I also needed `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` added to the parent

Edit: I also found that sometimes testing this required a refresh of my app.

Comment: This, plus the info in the accepted answer, fixed it for me. Thank you.